# Replicate car engine sound in html audio javascript

Tags: javascript, html, loops, audio

For a few duys i started working on a small js based browser racing game.
I dont have too much experience in javascript but i learn fast. The game is based on php and a little js for the animation. Also trying to implement node.js to make it realtime.

The game works but want to add sound so it would be more interesting... but i came across a little problem, gapless sound looping. Tryied several methods and frameworks but no results, only in chrome with some but thats not enough.

Please give some ideas/solutions/examples of how would you do it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: soundmanager2, howler, etc

Comment: Currently thinking that a good solution might be to learn a little flash and create a pitch shift for an engine sound and control the pitch via ajax call with javascript. Meanwhile i found a game called trigger rally that has a nice sound in chrome, trying to figure it out how the creator did it...

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make a reasonable engine sound by recording a real engine in 250 RPM increments, then created the additional very high RPM wav files by pitch shifting and increasing the volume. I then mix between these continually playing wav files using multiple HTML5 web audio gainNodes.

The pitch-shift is still noticable, but not to bad. If you want perfect sound you would will need to add additional wav files that start at one pitch and shift gradually to another, then logic to fade these in/out appropriately.

Looping the audio is done by having two wav files that overlap slightly and fade between them through the overlap, so you don't hear a click. Or alternatively create one long wav file beforehand using this technique so the clicks are infrequent.